# How to scan for values in two different variables, and switch them if they meet a condition

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am trying to find a way to scan through several variables for a specific value... null compared to 1.
Here is an example:

```
this.importDataObject("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt", "C:/Users/dell/Documents/tab 
excel/MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var fileArray = cFile.split('\n');
var Medical1 = this.getField("Medications 1");
var Medical3 = this.getField("Medications 3");
var Medical5 = this.getField("Medications 5");
var Medical7 = this.getField("Medications 7");
var Medical9 = this.getField("Medications 9");
var Medical11 = this.getField("Medications 11");
var Medical13 = this.getField("Medications 13");
var Medical15 = this.getField("Medications 15");
var Medical17 = this.getField("Medications 17"); 
var Medical19 = this.getField("Medications 19");
var Medical21 = this.getField("Medications 21");
var Medical23 = this.getField("Medications 23");
var Medical25 = this.getField("Medications 25");
var Medical27 = this.getField("Medications 27");
var Medical29 = this.getField("Medications 29");
var Medical31 = this.getField("Medications 31");
var Medical33 = this.getField("Medications 33");
var Medical35 = this.getField("Medications 35");
var Medical37 = this.getField("Medications 37");
var Medical39 = this.getField("Medications 39");
var MedicalIndex1 = null
var MedicalIndex3 = null
var MedicalIndex5 = null
var MedicalIndex7 = null
var MedicalIndex9 = null 
var MedicalIndex11 = null
var MedicalIndex13 = null
var MedicalIndex15 = null
var MedicalIndex17 = null
var MedicalIndex19 = null
var MedicalIndex21 = null
var MedicalIndex23 = null
var MedicalIndex25 = null
var MedicalIndex27 = null
var MedicalIndex29 = null
var MedicalIndex31 = null
var MedicalIndex33 = null
var MedicalIndex35 = null
var MedicalIndex37 = null 
var MedicalIndex39 = null
var MedicalArray = ["DEPRESSION", "ANGINA", "BIPOLAR DEPRESSION",         
"ATHEROSCLEROSIS", "HEART ATTACK"];
var temp = 0

var Medical1 = this.getField("Medications 1");
var Medical3 = this.getField("Medications 3");
var Medical5 = this.getField("Medications 5");
var MedicalIndex1 = null
var MedicalIndex3 = null
var MedicalIndex5 = null

var i, Index;
 for (i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) { 
  Index = fileArray[i].indexOf(Medical5.value);
  if(Index > -1) Cartographer = fileArray[i].split('\t');
  if(Index > -1) MedAnalysis = Cartographer[0];
  if(Index > -1) BrandAnalysis = Cartographer[1];
  if(Index > -1) DiagAnalysis = Cartographer[2];
  if(Index > -1) CodeAnalysis = Cartographer[3];
  if(Index > -1) DiagSearch = DiagAnalysis.indexOf(MedicalArray[0]);
  if(Index > -1 && DiagSearch != -1) MedicalIndex5 = 1;
  if(Index > -1) DiagSearch = DiagAnalysis.indexOf(MedicalArray[1]);
  if(Index > -1 && DiagSearch != -1) MedicalIndex5 = 1;
  if(Index > -1) DiagSearch = DiagAnalysis.indexOf(MedicalArray[2]);
  if(Index > -1 && DiagSearch != -1) MedicalIndex5 = 1;
  if(Index > -1) DiagSearch = DiagAnalysis.indexOf(MedicalArray[3]);
  if(Index > -1 && DiagSearch != -1) MedicalIndex5 = 1;
  if(Index > -1) DiagSearch = DiagAnalysis.indexOf(MedicalArray[4]);
  if(Index > -1 && DiagSearch != -1) MedicalIndex5 = 1;
}
```

Edit: I left one of the blocks of code that scan for whether the Medical variables has any of the values in the MedicalArray.   There are roughly 15 of these blocks, so I put only one to save space and time.

I would like to be able to find the MedicalIndexes with the value of 1, and switch them to be the first Medical variables... so if MedicalIndex 27 had a value of 1, then Medical27 would switch places with one of the first Medical variables that are null.

Comment: Please post a full working sample of your code and what your output should be exactly

Comment: It's done, here you go my man

Comment: I still find it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, what are the `MedicalIndexes` exactly? And what do you mean by switch them? Switch them with whom? Also you're saying `if MedicalIndex 27 had a value of 1` what exactly is MedicalIndex 27? Is it the variable `MedicalIndex27`? And I think it's better to put your variables in an array with a `key=>value` schema

Comment: Basically, all of the MedicalIndex variables are null to begin with. 
based on the user's input for the Medication fields, the program will scan to see if the user typed in a qualifying Medical diagnoses.
The qualifying Diagnoses should be in the first five Medical variables, and if the user puts in a qualifying diagnosis in, "Medical27" it should be moved to either of the first five Medical variables.